# Hadoop: NullPointerException when calling getFsStatistics

Tags: java, hadoop, permissions, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm encountering the following Exception when running a MapReduce job taking a file stored on HDFS as input:

```
15/03/27 17:18:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1427398929405_0005_m_000005_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.getFsStatistics(Task.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

I don't have a good sense of what this means myself, other than this looks possibly related to file permissions. I've also have found the following other StackOverflow post with the same Exception/trace: [NullPointerException with MR2 in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734440/nullpointerexception-with-mr2-in-windows).

To summarize the post: this Exception was caused due to the hadoop being run as a different user than that of the MR job.

I've tried the following:

- `chmod`-ing all files and directories in HDFS to 777 (just to experiment)
- running the hadoop job with `sudo`

but neither approach has yielded any results.

I'm running all Hadoop processes on localhost ("pseudo-distributed mode"). I started hadoop using `start-yarn.sh` and `start-dfs.sh` with my normal local user. I'm running the hadoop job with the same user. I've also set `dfs.datanode.data.dir` and `dfs.namenode.name.dir` to paths on my local machine to which I have permission to read/write with my local user. I've set `dfs.permissions.enabled` to `false`.

Am I misinterpreting this Exception? Is there anything else I should try? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was my own `FileSplit` subclass causing the problem. I was not correctly (de)serializing the the FileSplit's `Path`, so when send across the wire this field became `null`. Hadoop calls `getFsStatistics` on the null Path, causing the `NullPointerException`.